# How to open more than activity from Main Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, computer-science

I have created 2 Activities in Kotlin other than main activity (total 3 activity,
1.activity _Main, 
2. activity _A, 
3. activity _B)....
 now I want to make something that when button A is clicked than activity_A is open and when button B is clicked than activity_B is open.

Comment: this is some basic development. you need to research onclicklisteners in kotlin. welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
class activity_Main : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main)


            /*------------------------------------*/
            buttonA.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java))
            }


            /*------------------------------------*/
            buttonB.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java))
            }


        }
}
```